# Copy a range in a email HTML body

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to copy a range of values in a email HTML body.

So far, I saw on another trend here the way to copy a cell in the body only, and it works:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim mainWB As Workbook
    Dim CCID
    Dim SendID
    Dim subject
    Dim body
    Dim otlApp
    Dim OLmail As MailItem

    Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OLmail = otlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Dim oAttach As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sPath As String

    SendID = NameToRange("Email_To")
    subject = "Email1"

    With OLmail
        .To = SendID
        If CCID <> "" Then
          .cc = CCID
        End If
        .subject = subject
        .Attachments.Add "S:\Documents\Graph1.jpeg", olByValue, 0

        .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<B>Hello,</B><br>" _
        & "<br><B>Introduction</B><br>" & _
                    "<br>" & mainWB.range([101, 42],[102, 50]).Value & _
                    "<br><B>Graph:</B><br>" _
                    & "<img src='Graph1.jpg'" & "width='600' height='300'>" _

        .display
    End With
end sub
```

Comment: Just trying to understand your question. Are you trying to parse an email with VBA?

Comment: I send an email via VBA. It is all working, I send pictures and text. Now, I try to send a range of values in this email (html body) and I struggle.

Comment: Ok, I assume you followed some web tutorial, blog, or other stack overflow question when creating your original code. Can you please send the link for that? It will provide context for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define the range, then loop through it like this.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim mainWB As Workbook
Dim CCID
Dim SendID
Dim subject
Dim body
Dim otlApp
Dim OLmail As MailItem

'******************************
Dim rng As Range             '*
Dim cell As Range            '*
Dim EMBody As String         '*
'******************************
Set rng = Range("") 'range   '*
For Each cell In rng         '*
EMBody = EMBody & cell.Value '*
EMBody = EMBody & Chr(13)    '*
Next cell                    '*
'******************************

Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OLmail = otlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim oAttach As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sPath As String

SendID = NameToRange("Email_To")
subject = "Email1"

With OLmail
    .To = SendID
    If CCID <> "" Then .CC = CCID
    End If
    .subject = subject
    .Attachments.Add "S:\Documents\Graph1.jpeg", olByValue, 0
    .body = EMBody
    .HTMLBody = "" 'put whatever else you need besides the range values
    .display
End With

End Sub
```